# Ubuntu 18.04 ! LaTeX Error: File `tikzpicture.sty' not found?

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and have installed the whole texlive i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

but still while building the PDF report from r-markdown i.e. rmd file I get the following error due to missing `tikzpicture` package ...

```
! LaTeX Error: File `tikzpicture.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

How do you fix this? what needs to be done to install tikzpicture?

Comment: I don't think there is a `tikzpicture` package. Rather, the package name's `tikz`, and the _environment_ it defines is `tikzpicture`

Comment: That is, replace `\usepackage{tikzpicture}` by `\usepackage{tikz}`. May the <s>force</s> `tikz` be with you!

Comment: And now you know why we always ask for a minimal example of the code you're using.